# NoReverseMatch Django Tutorial 1.8

Tags: python, django

so I started on the generic views section of the tutorial, until which point everything was smooth sailing, working perfectly and then I get this error:
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'polls/(?P[0-9]+)/vote/$']

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name ='vote'),
]
```

And here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext, loader 
from django.http import Http404
from .models import Choice, Quesion
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
# Create your views here.

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Quesion.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Quesion
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Quesion
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Quesion, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': p,
            'error_message':"No choice selected",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results',args=(p.id,)))
```

And here is my detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"    value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_txt }}   </label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="vote" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that `DetailView` doesn't provide a `question` variable in the template, but provides one called `object` instead. So all instances of `question` in the template needs to be changed to `object`.

Secondly, the URL is expecting a keyword argument `question_id`, but you're passing a non-keyword argument to the `{% url %}` tag. You need to change that to say `question_id=object.id`. Your `detail.html` should look like this:

```
<h1>{{ object.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question_id=object.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in object.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}"    value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_txt }}   </label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="vote" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes this worked. Thanks. Looks like the typo I'd made for Question in the models was the main problem.

Comment: Ha - I didn't even notice that.